# How to make two adjacent tables with vertical buttons between them in Bootstrap v4

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I am working on survey application with Asp.Net MVC. I have 2 adjacent tables with vertical button group between them in Bootstrap v4. The button group has two button which provides to move the selected row/rows from left to right or right to left. But I couldn't fit them properly. I have a problem with right table. Sometimes right table moves under the left table. I want to be close each other. this is the design I make where I make mistakes.

```
<div class="row flex-row">
    <div class="col form-group">
        <table id="leftTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered accent-blue table-responsive ">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Soru No</th>
                <th>Soru Adı</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1 flex-col">
        <div class="btn-group-vertical">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" id="btnRight" style="margin-bottom: 3px"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>Soru Ekle</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" id="btnLeft"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>Soru Sil</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col form-group">
        <table id="rightTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered accent-blue table-responsive">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Soru No</th>
                    <th>Soru Adı</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work and fix your problem.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col">
        <!--Left table code-->
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-auto">
         <!--Button code-->
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <!--Right table code-->
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: my problem is solved. But there is a shift in the search box of 'datatable'. You see on  https://ibb.co/zb8p2Ps

Answer (score 0):

Since bootstrap is responsive, in the mobile view, the 3rd col in your row (right table) will definitely move under the 2nd col (btn-group-vertical). All the div with class name as "col" will occupy 12 column width. Hence they are underneath each other.

If you want the tables to be close each other, no matter the view port then use the following code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <!--Left table code-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <!--Button code-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <!--Right table code-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, But I didn't work.The fact that the button group occupies one third of the space does not look nice on the screen. What I want is that the width of the column in the middle takes up only the width of the button width. I want the remaining part to be divided into 2 equal parts and distributed to the tables.

Comment: ```<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-5">
        <!--Left table code-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <!--Button code-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
        <!--Right table code-->
    </div>
</div>```